# How to handle React Hooks and Style Tags?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, styles

I started with React and try to create a webside with Python + Flask + React.
So I created a Python + Flask backend and React frontend and it worked to
show items from backend to my frontend.

Now I found this tutorial to create a navbar at the left side of my webside

I tried it until 22:24, in this video: [YouTube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=react%20navbar) but I don't know why it is working in tutorial and I receive errors with the same code. Can you help me?

My Problem is, that I receive this message in my browser:

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of
> the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the
> following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

> ```
> React 2
>     resolveDispatcher
>     useRef
>     BrowserRouter index.tsx:151
>     React 11
>     renderWithHooks
>     mountIndeterminateComponent
>     beginWork
>     callCallback
>     invokeGuardedCallbackDev
>     invokeGuardedCallback
>     beginWork$1
>     performUnitOfWork
>     workLoopSync
>     renderRootSync
>     performConcurrentWorkOnRoot
> workLoop scheduler.development.js:266
> flushWork scheduler.development.js:239
> performWorkUntilDeadline scheduler.development.js:533 react.development.js:1465
> ```

Sidebar.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import * as FaIcons from 'react-icons/fa';
import * as AiIcons from 'react-icons/ai';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";


const Nav = styled.div`   
    background: #15171c;
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    `;

 const NavIcon = styled(Link)`    
    margin-left: 2rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    `;

const Sidebar = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Nav>
                <NavIcon to='#'>
                    <FaIcons.FaBars />
                </NavIcon>
            </Nav>
        </>
    );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

App.js:

```
    import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
    import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar';
    import './App.css';
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
    
    /**
     * useState = received backend_data + rendering
     * useEffect = fetch backend_API at first rendering
     * */
    
    function App() {
    
        const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    
        useEffect(() => {
            fetch("http://localhost:5000/menu").then(
                res => res.json()
            ).then(
                data => {
                    setData(data)
                    console.log(data)
                }
            )
        }, [])
    
        return (
            <div>
                <Router>
                    <Sidebar />
                </Router>
    
    
                {(typeof data.menu === 'undefined') ? (
                    <p>Loading...</p>
                ):(
                    data.menu.map((menu, i) => (
                        <p key={i}>{menu}</p>
                    ))
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default App
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx problem is solved by installing and importing CORS

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an error message - it points you to where the problem might be:

```
...
BrowserRouter index.tsx:151
...
```

Check line 151 of your `index.tsx` file or attach it to your post.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, I don't know about a index.tsx
Maybe it will be generated while browser compiling?

Here is my index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(

    <App />

);
```

And my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this an answer, or part of your question?

Comment: It was a answer because someone asked to put my index.html in my post. But It is solved

Comment: So, it should be part of your question, right?